# why does greatest function throw error pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame; which has multiple columns with name `fib_1`, `fib_3`, `fib_5` and so on.

I am trying to create one column `Fib` with values `max(fib_1,fib_2,fib_3)`

```
df.withColumn("Fib", greatest(list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('fib_'),df.columns)))).show()
```

I get below error:

> ValueError: greatest should take at least two columns

`fib_1`, `fib_2`, `fib_2` have values 0 and 1.

The dataframe has other columns with different data types

Answer (score 1):

You have to add **`*`** to unpack the list of columns you pass to the `greatest` function.

If you look at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest), it takes `*cols` as parameter:

> `pyspark.sql.functions.greatest(*cols)`

So just use:

```
df.withColumn("Fib", greatest(*list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('fib_'), df.columns)))).show()
```

Comment: pyspark.sql.functions.greatest(*cols) - doesnt work..It throws error. Also I think I am trying to add a list to a dataframe...that logic is breaking somewhere